# How do I hide and show my function after a period of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide my text for a certain period of time and then show using a function. Currently it's blinking I don't want that want it to hide wait for a few second then show.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.hotKeys').hide();
  $('.shortcut').hide();
}, 5000);
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $hotKeys = $('.hotKeys');
  var $shortcut = $('.shortcut');

  function runIt() {
    $hotKeys.animate({
      opacity: '0.6'
    }, 1000);
    $hotKeys.animate({
      opacity: '0'
    }, 1000, runIt);
    $shortcut.animate({
      opacity: '0.6'
    }, 1000);
    $shortcut.animate({
      opacity: '0'
    }, 1000, runIt);
  }
  runIt();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="hotKeys">hot keys</h4>
<ul class="shortcut">
  <li>h</li>
  <li>p</li>
  <li>s</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I've tried placing the hide function in different areas of the code and I thought '.delay()' would do the trick but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: use `setTimeout()` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Do you want to show/hide only once or loop forever?

Comment: Just once then start function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/bvxft9de/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
   $('.hotKeys').hide();
   $('.shortcut').hide();
   
   var $hotKeys = $('.hotKeys');
   var $shortcut = $('.shortcut');
   function runIt() { 
     $('.hotKeys').show();
     $('.shortcut').show();
     $hotKeys.animate({opacity:'0.6'}, 1000);
     $hotKeys.animate({opacity:'0'}, 1000, runIt);
     $shortcut.animate({opacity:'0.6'}, 1000);
     $shortcut.animate({opacity:'0'}, 1000, runIt);
   }
   
   setTimeout(function(){
     runIt();
   }, 2000);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="hotKeys">hot keys</h4>
<ul class="shortcut">
  <li>h</li>
  <li>p</li>
  <li>s</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Initially, your text will be hidden for 2sec, then it will start animation.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks man! i had it like this i just put it in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `setTimeout`

For example:

```
var milliseconds = 1000; //1 sec
setTimeout(function runIt() {
       $hotKeys.animate({opacity:'0.6'}, 1000);
       $hotKeys.animate({opacity:'0'}, 1000, runIt);
       $shortcut.animate({opacity:'0.6'}, 1000);
       $shortcut.animate({opacity:'0'}, 1000, runIt);
     },milliseconds );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 

setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('.hotKeys').show();
  $('.shortcut').show();
  }, 5000);
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.hotKeys').hide();
 $('.shortcut').hide();
 var $hotKeys = $('.hotKeys');
 var $shortcut = $('.shortcut');
 function runIt() {
 $hotKeys.animate({opacity:'0.6'}, 1000);
 $hotKeys.animate({opacity:'0'}, 1000, runIt);
 $shortcut.animate({opacity:'0.6'}, 1000);
 $shortcut.animate({opacity:'0'}, 1000, runIt);
     }
 runIt();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="hotKeys">hot keys</h4>
<ul class="shortcut">
  <li>h</li>
  <li>p</li>
  <li>s</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $hotKeys = $('.hotKeys');
  var $shortcut = $('.shortcut');

  function runIt() {
    $hotKeys.animate({
      opacity: '0.6'
    }, 1000);
    $hotKeys.animate({
      opacity: '0'
    }, 1000);
    $shortcut.animate({
      opacity: '0.6'
    }, 1000);
    $shortcut.animate({
      opacity: '0'
    }, 1000);
  }
  runIt();
  
  setInterval(function() {
  if($('.hotKeys').is(':visible') && $('.shortcut').is(':visible')) {
  $('.hotKeys').hide();
  $('.shortcut').hide();
  }
  else
  {
  $hotKeys.animate({
      opacity: '1'
    }, 1000);
    $hotKeys.animate({
      opacity: '1'
    }, 1000);
    $shortcut.animate({
      opacity: '1'
    }, 1000)
    $shortcut.animate({
      opacity: '1'
    }, 1000);
  $('.hotKeys').show();
  $('.shortcut').show();
  }
  
}, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="hotKeys">hot keys</h4>
<ul class="shortcut">
  <li>h</li>
  <li>p</li>
  <li>s</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

try it. It's not **blinking**